# How do I make an ajax call with CakePHP 3 (alpha/beta versions)

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Normally, making an ajax call is fairly simple. You just unlock the action in the controller and specify in the function that you're using ajax in:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['checkUsername']);
    $this->Security->unlockedActions =['checkUsername'];
}

public function checkUsername() {
    $this->request->allowMethod(['ajax']);  
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, in CakePHP 3 this is giving me the black hole error below as a response:

```
code: 400
message: "The request has been black-holed"
url: "/users/checkUsername.json"
```

It also works the same way when it's /users/checkUsername (instead of the .json, which was a recommended solution elsewhere). Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it should work just as in 2.x. It does work when you deactivate the Sec. component alltogether, right?

Comment: Actually, taking out the Security component breaks the whole site. What's up with that, and maybe that's part of the issue...?

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3.0 it should be:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
  parent::beforeFilter($event);
  $this->Auth->allow(['checkUsername']);
  $this->Security->config('unlockedActions', ['checkUsername']);
}
```